# Is there any way to count the number of times a string is present in another given string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, count, libraries

I tried to create a program which returns the number of times a certain string occurs in the main string.

```
main_string="ABCDCDC"

find_string="CDC"

print(main_string.count(find_string))
```

Output=1

....
But there are 2 CDC. Is there any other ways to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `re`gex:

```
print(len(re.findall(fr"(?={find_string})", main_string)))
```

Or try using this list comprehension:

```
x = len(find_string)
print(len([main_string[i:x + i] for i in range(len(main_string)) if main_string[i:x + i] == find_string]))
```

Both codes output:

```
2
```

Comment: Or this pattern ```"(?=CDC)"```

Comment: @Sujay Yeah that's nice, edited my answer

Comment: Also escaping ```fr"(?={find_string})"```

Comment: @Sujay Ah yeah edited my answer